# When a self-adjoin operator is invariant wrt any orthogonal projection

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Given a  linear operator $F$ on an inner product space $V$.

If $F$ is self-adjoin and satisfies that
$$
P F P^T = F
$$
for any orthogonal linear transformation $P: V\to V$,  is it true that $F = c I$ i.e. scale of the identity operator for some $c \in \mathbb R$?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let $v$ be a eigenvector of $F$ to the eigenvalue $\lambda$.
Then
$$
\lambda v = Fv = P FP^Tv.
$$
Multiplying from the left with $P^T$ yields
$$
\lambda P^Tv = F(P^Tv).
$$
Hence, $P^Tv$ is a eigenvector of $F$, too, for all orthogonal $P$. This implies that all non-zero vectors of $V$ are  eigenvectors of $F$. Hence, $F$ has at most one eigenvalue. And since $F$ is self-adjoint hence diagonalizable, it follows $F=cI$.

Comment: Thanks, but $P$ isn't an orthogonal projection but orthogonal linear transformation

Comment: If $P$ is a orthogonal linear transformation then $P^TP=I$.